# Why is Raspbian Stretch's image is SO HUGE on Window?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, software-installation, raspbian-stretch, image

I downloaded Raspbian Stretch with Desktop to install on my PI. Once it completed, I tried to extract the file, but the window complained that there is not enough space that I need some 470 GB MORE. What is going on? I simply went to https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/. Then started to download ZIP file. Any idea.

Comment: You did something wrong - the image, when expanded, should only be 4GB if I recall

Comment: Try using 7-Zip.

Comment: @kwasmich You are right. I was using built-in windows zip extractor and It didn't work. I downloaded 7-zip and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question was requested by two people to be closed, I think it will help someone who is working with PI extensively like me.

When you have a problem like this, simply download 7-zip for your system and extract the Zip file with this program.

Comment: Alternely you could just read the instructions on the Foundation site.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspbian stretch image is 1.9Gb and when unpacked becomes 4.7GB. Are you using a big enough SD card. 8GB minimum

Comment: No, I am downloading the image on to my PC hardrive (500GB) and then extracting it on my PC.